# Fatal error: Class 'FilesystemIterator' not found

Tags: php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$it = new FilesystemIterator("C:");
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
 printf("%30s%20u\n", $fileinfo->getFilename(),
 $fileinfo->getSize());
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error code :**

Fatal error: Class 'FilesystemIterator' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\library.php on line 4

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The [`FilesystemIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.filesystemiterator.php) class is only available from PHP 5.3.0

Comment: currently 5.2.9

Comment: Well there's your problem. Keep in mind that anything below 7.3 is completely [unsupported](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). You should update ASAP

Comment: FileSystemIterator requires PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: oh ok, thanks for helping